# How can I shorter cording?

Tags: r

I have data frame like this.

```r
head(bus_pop)[-c(1:2)]
   a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8  a9 a10 a11 a12 a13
1   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  77 127 160 238  76
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 113 180 163 300  60
3   0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0 106  89 100 310  48
4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  41  97  66 285  41
5  19 34  1  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   9
6 157 21  2  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0   0  10
```

And I want to create new column "total". So I write code like this.

```r
bus_pop %>% 
  mutate(total = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12 + a13)
```

How can I make to short cording?

Comment: `bus_pop$total <- rowSums(bus_pop[-c(1:2)], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Perfect and so quick. Thank you.